# saving udid string to a text file

Tags: ios, objective-c, save, udid

hi i'm working on a simple activation app in iOS. i want to save udid in a text file and equal text file with current udid but i can't save udid to text file

```
NSString *udid = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"h" ofType:@"txt"]];

NSMutableString *text = [NSMutableString stringWithContentsOfURL:fileURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"text is : %@",text);

NSString *text1 = text;

NSString *y;

if ([text1 isEqualToString:y]) {

    [text appendString:udid];

    NSString *myURLString = [fileURL absoluteString];

    [text writeToFile:myURLString atomically: YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    NSLog(@"saved to file : %@",text);

}else {

    if ([text isEqualToString:udid]) {

        NSLog(@"yes thats it");
        lable.text = @"yes thats it";

    }else {
        NSLog(@"nononono");
        exit(0);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with your code.  Starting with:

```
if ([text1 isEqualToString:y]) {
```

where is "y" defined or declared?

Also, you never look at the error parameter while writing to a file.  Change this:

```
[text writeToFile:myURLString atomically: YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

to this:

```
NSError *error;

BOOL success = [text writeToFile:myURLString atomically: YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if(NO == success)
{
    NSLog(@"error from writing to %@ is %@", myURLString, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

And you might have a better clue as to what kind of error you're running into.

Lastly, with your comment, you've made it clear you're trying to write a file *directly into* the bundle of your application.  Which is a big (sandboxed) no no.

Instead of:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"h" ofType:@"txt"]];
```

do this instead:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = [paths firstObject];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[basePath stringByAppendingString:@"/h.txt"]];
```

and this will save your file into the *Documents* directory, which is a legal place to save files.

Comment: it's give me :  error from writing to file:///Users/mji/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0-64/Applications/C48463FB-F7F0-47AD-A40A-958A3583C29E/active%20text.app/h.txt is The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)

Comment: you shouldn't be trying to write into the app's bundle, that's not allowed.

Comment: now it's give me this when i want to save udid to file     error from writing to file:///Users/mji/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0-64/Applications/C48463FB-F7F0-47AD-A40A-958A3583C29E/Documents/h.txt is (null)

Comment: but in NSLog says to me h.text is : null